# Flutter android release Build APK error: No signature of method

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle

I was building the APK after checking that the flutter android app was normally run in the emulator.
I add Keystore and change: `signingConfig.release` in `app:build.gradle`
But it has an error: `No signature of the method`.
What is this problem?
**This is app:build.gradle code**

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
    def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
    if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
      localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
      }
    }

    def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
    def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
    if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
      keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
    }

    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with 
        flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }

    def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
    if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
      flutterVersionCode = '1'
    }

    def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
    if (flutterVersionName == null) {
      flutterVersionName = '1.0'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'
    apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

    android {
      compileSdkVersion 31
      ndkVersion '23.0.7599858'

      aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'tflite'
        noCompress 'lite'
      }

      sourceSets{
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
      }

      defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.healme.wisehealthylife"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
      }

      signingConfig {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
      }

      buildTypes {
          release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
      }

    }
 
    flutter {
      source '../..'
    }

    dependencies {
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
      implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
      implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')
      implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
      implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

**This is project:build.gradle code**

```
    buildscript {
      ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
      ext {
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
      }
      repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
      }

      dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
      }
    }

    allprojects {
      repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
      }
    }

    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
      project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
      project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

**This is the error message:**

Terminal: C:\Users\SW2148\flutter_project\Wise Healthy Life\testlogin>flutter build apk --split-per-abi

Building with sound null safety

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\SW2148\flutter_project\Wise Healthy Life\testlogin\android\app\build.gradle' line: 35
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_htngxzdn1u0d7ezwn29dznwg.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_htngxzdn1u0d7ezwn29d
> znwg$_run_closure2) values: [build_htngxzdn1u0d7ezwn29dznwg$_run_closure2@3797f448]

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan t
  o get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           16.0s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

What should I do?